# Show that minimizing $Tr(Q)$ equals minimizing $x_0^{T}\:Q\:x_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, kalman-filter

In two different textbooks about Kalman Filter, the so-called Estimator Gain Matrix G is obtained as result of two different minimization problems, i would like to show or at least giustify that the two problems have the same minimizer G.

$$arg\underset{G\,\in\,\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}}{min} \;\; Tr(Q)$$

$$arg \underset{G\,\in\,\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}}{min} \;\; x_0^{T}\:Q\:x_0$$

where $$Q=\int_{0}^{t} \,e^{(A+GC)\beta}\,(\Psi+G\Gamma G^{T})\:e^{(A+GC)^{T}\beta}\,d\beta$$

with

$\;\;\;\Psi$ $[n\times n]$ diagonal matrix

$\;\;\;\Gamma$ $[m\times m]$ diagonal matrix

$\;\;\;G$ $[n\times m]$ matrix

$\;\;\;A$ $[n\times n]$ matrix

$\;\;\;C$ $[m\times n]$ matrix

$\;\;\;x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}  \;\;s.t. \;x_0 \neq0$

$\;\;\;A, G, C \;s.t. (A+GC)$ negative definite matrix

$\;\;\;\beta \in \mathbb{R} \,,\:t \in \mathbb{R}$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I assume that the following dimension should have been $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes you are correct, i'll update the text, thanks

Comment: I just tested this numerically for $n=2$ and $m=1$ and minimizing either cost function did yield the same $G$ for any $x_0\neq0$. So even though the cost functions are not equivalent, they do have the same optimum.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to prove this fact? That is actually the aim of the post

Comment: The only thing I could come up with from the top of my head is that a Kalman filter is the dual of LQR. And for a Kalman filter the first cost function would be a measure of the power of the state estimation error, while the second cost function is more related to LQR.

Comment: Exactly, the first one is reachable from mean squared state estimation error minimization (or 'error power' minimization), while the second one can be solved with Jacobi-Bellman equation in the special case of LQR problem.

The way the two problems are presented, they seem to have the same minimizer just by coincidence. The question is then: can this be proved beforehand?

Comment: Ok i edited the text because it was not clear, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

For the first optimization problem one can use that the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of all its eigenvalues. But the second cost function has the following lower and upper bound

$$
\lambda_\min(Q)\,\|x_0\|^2 \leq x_0^\top Q\,x_0 \leq \lambda_\max(Q)\,\|x_0\|^2,
$$

with $\lambda_\min(Q)$ and $\lambda_\max(Q)$ the smallest and biggest eigenvalue of $Q$ respectively. So these cost functions are not the same and the second cost function would be dependent on the choice for $x_0$. I think only when $\lambda_\min(Q) = \lambda_\max(Q)$ then the cost function would be identical independent of $x_0$, but I do not see a reason why  this would be the case given the definition of $Q$.

It can be noted though that $Q$ for a given $G$ [has to satisfy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1358.pdf) the following Lyapunov equation

$$
\mathcal{A}\,Q + Q\,\mathcal{A}^\top = e^{\mathcal{A}\,t} \left(\Psi + G\,\Gamma\,G^\top\right) e^{\mathcal{A}^\top t} - \Psi - G\,\Gamma\,G^\top,
$$

with $\mathcal{A} = A + G\,C$.